# Why am I allowed to cast base class View into a derived view in Android?

Tags: java, android

It's very usual to call findViewById(int id) to return a desired view. However, we need to type cast the returned View into the view we need. Like this:

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
```

However, when I create a base Class and a derived Class, I can't do the same.

```
public class Food {
    public String speak(){
        return "I'm a food!";
    }
```

}

```
public class Peach extends Food{

}

public class ClassePrincipal {
    public static void main (String args[]) { 
        Peach peach= (Peach ) new Food();
        System.out.println(peach.speak());
    }
```

I get the following error:
run:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   PacoteMinicursoAndroid.Comida cannot be cast to
>   PacoteMinicursoAndroid.Peach at
>   PacoteMinicursoAndroid.ClassePrincipal.main(ClassePrincipal.java:7)
>   C:\Users\Miguel\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1 FALHA NA CONSTRUÇÃO (translates: fails at building) (total time: 0 seconds)

Why can I cast views in Android like that?

I can't really see the difference between casting View to a TextView (since TextView extends from View) and casting Food to a Peach (since Peach extends from Food). From what I know about Inheritance, a base class can receive an instance from a derived class, and not the opposite.

Comment: Um, `Food` is not a `Peach`.

Comment: Because `findViewById(R.id.myTextView);` actually does return a `TextView` (in this case), while `Food` will never be a `Peach`. I recommend reading some basic Java tutorials to understand what programming to interfaces means and how casting works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `findViewById(R.id.myTextView)` returns a `View` which is actually a `TextView` but the compiler does not know that. It only knows that there will be a `View` object, that's why you tell the compiler explicitly that it is a `TextView` by casting it.

Your declaration and casting is wrong

```
 Peach peach= (Peach) new Food();
```

Because while `Food` extends `Peach` it will never be a `Peach` object, but always a `Food` object. Typecasting is a developer tool to give the compiler more information at compile-time.

Comment: what you mean at "returns a View which is actually a TextView but the compiler does not know that"? I don't really see the difference between casting View to a TextView (since TextView extends from View) and casting Food to a Peach(since Peach extends from Food).

Comment: @MigueldeSousa To say it really simple `findViewById` has return type `View` and `new Food()` has return type `Food`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it.

since findViewById(int id) is allowed to return a View class, it's also allowed to return any derived class, like TextView. It's a polymorphic method.

example:

```
public class Food{

    public Food getPeach(){
        return new Peach();
    }
}

public class Pessego extends Comida{

}
```

and then in the main method:

```
Food food = new Food();
Peach peach = (Peach) food.getPeach();
```

getPeach() is a polymorphic method just like findViewById(int id).